# How to upload multiple image with rename in php and insert database?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hi how to upload multiple image in php with rename and insert databse?
my code is below but not rename and insert 1 rows in datase.

```
 $uploads_dir = 'uploaded/up/';
        foreach ($_FILES["layout_plan_no_of_images"]["error"] as $i => $k) {
        if ($k == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $tmp_name = $_FILES["layout_plan_no_of_images"]["tmp_name"][$i];
            $name = $_FILES["layout_plan_no_of_images"]["name"][$i];
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
        }
        $sql="INSERT INTO projects (layout_plan_no_of_images)VALUES(':layout_plan_no_of_images')";
            $sql_result = $db->queryPrepared($sql, array(
                ':layout_plan_no_of_images' => $_FILES['layout_plan_no_of_images']['name']
            ));
```

Comment: you are uploading single or multiple images???

Comment: You say you are uploading multiple images. The uploaded images would therefore be in an array, and you need to refer to them as such. Easiest way to see this is to print_r ($_FILES).

Comment: too much missing code, and who knows if you even executed the query. check for errors, good luck

Comment: what is wrong with the code ?

Answer (score 2):

Hi try to below code may be help for with rename

```
foreach($_FILES["layout_plan_no_of_images"]['name'] as $key=>$tmp_name){
    $file_name=$_FILES["layout_plan_no_of_images"]["name"][$key];
    $file_tmp=$_FILES["layout_plan_no_of_images"]["tmp_name"][$key];
    $ext=pathinfo($file_name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $filename=basename($file_name,$ext);
    $newFileName=(string)$filename.time().".".$ext;
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp=$_FILES["layout_plan_no_of_images"]["tmp_name"][$key],"uploaded/".$newFileName);           
    $concateFiles .= $comma.$newFileName;
    $comma = ',';
}
$sql="INSERT INTO projects (`layout_plan_no_of_images`, `pid`)VALUES($concateFiles)";
    $sql_result = $db->queryPrepared($sql, array(
    ':layout_plan_no_of_images'  => $concateFiles,
));
```

Comment: can you give a summary of what you changes and what works now that didn't before? for future and other references ?